# How do I find ordered pair, given slope of the tangent line?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

The function is $f(x) = x^3 + 9x^2 + 36x + 10$ and the slope given is $9$.

I found the derivative and set it equal to $9$, but I ended up with $x = (-9,-33)$ and the answer is $(-3,-44)$.

I've asked two Math majors and neither knows how to find it.

Where did I go wrong and how can I answer the next one correctly?

Work:

\begin{align*}
& f(x) = x^3 + 9x^2 + 36x + 10 \Rightarrow f^{\prime}(x) = 3x^2 + 18x + 36 \Rightarrow 3x^2 + 18x + 36 = 9 \Rightarrow\\\\
& 3x^2 + 18x = -27 \Rightarrow 3x ( x + 6 ) = -27 \Rightarrow 3x = -27  x + 6 = -27 \Rightarrow
x = -3  x = -33
\end{align*}

Comment: $   3x ( x + 6 ) = -27 \Rightarrow 3x = -27  x + 6 = -27 $ is not valid

Comment: Which point are you given? If $x=9$ then you don't set the derivative equal to $9$, you plug $9$ into the derivative. Are you being asked to find the point on the curve whose derivative is $9$?

Comment: I meant $3x(x+6)=-27\Rightarrow 3x=-27x+6$ is not valid

Comment: It's confusing if you use $x$ to represent the ordered pair, the independent variable, and the dependent variable

Comment: @JohnDouma:  Since the answer is given to be $(-3,-44),$ I assume OP was asked to find the point on the curve where the derivative is $9$, though it's not stated clearly

Answer (score 1):

So we know the derivative value (i.e. tangent slope gradient), but not the point on $f(x)$. 
First derive and set derivative to 9.

$ f'(x) = 3x^{2}+18x+36=9 $ 
$ \Rightarrow x^{2}+6x+12-3=0 $           *(divide by 3 then subtract 3)* 
$ \Rightarrow (x+3)^{2}=0 $ 
$ \therefore x=-3$           *($x$-ordinate of the point on f(x))*

To find the $y$-oordinate substitute $x$ back into $f(x)$: 
$f(-3)=-44$

Hence at the point $(-3,-44)$ the function $f(x)$ has a tangent slope gradient of $9$.

Answer (score 0):

You got $3x^2+18x=-27.$

This is equivalent to $3x^2+18x+27=0$ or $x^2+6x+9=0$  or $(x+3)^2=0$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: That's because I'm trying to find the slope of the tangent line at point 9, so I set it equal to 9 and 9 - 36 = -27

Comment: Also, I didn't get 3x=-27x+6=-27 those are separate, I got 3x = -27 AND x+6 = -27 in order to get an ordered pair

Comment: @T.Saruwatari:  I agree with you that $3x^2+18x=-27$ follows from $f'(x)=9$; I was showing the correct solution from that point onward

Comment: That would only give me two sets of x = -3. But, I digress, I'm just going to take the L because I've spent 3 hours online searching for resources and I don't seem to be competent enough to figure it out

Comment: I thought you said the answer is $-3,$ and I showed how to get that:  $x=-3$ and $f(x)=-44$

Comment: @T.Saruwatari:    $3x(x+6)=-27$ does not mean $3x=-27$ and $x+6=-27$; rather, it means $x=-3,$ as I showed

Answer (score 0):

From your second line at start you get by simplification for given slope $9$

$$ (x+3)^2 =0$$

Plug $x=-3$ into $y=f(x)$ expression and you directly get $ y=-44$ so that this point ( called inflection point ) is described as

$$ y= f(x)= x^3+9x^2+36x+10 $$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}= 3x^2+18x +36 $$

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=6x+18 $$

$$ \frac{d^3y}{dx^3}=6 $$

$$ x=-3,y=-44,\frac{dy}{dx}=9, \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0  $$

all of which is seen in [the WA plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%20%2B9%20x%5E2%20%2B%2036%20x%20%2B%2010)